# How to get all URLs within a page fom oddsportal?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a code that scrapes all URLs from oddsportal.com main page.
I want the subsequent links to all pages within the parent URL
e.g.
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/
has further pages i.e. https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/, https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2019/results/, etc.
How can I get that?

[image: Inspect element]

My existing code:

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/results/#soccer'
headers = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'}
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
base_url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com'
a = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'foo': 'f'})

# This set will have all the URLs of the main page
s = set()
for i in a:
    s.add(base_url + i['href'])
s = list(s)
# This will filter for all soccer URLs
s = [x for x in s if '/soccer/' in x]
s = pd.DataFrame(s)
print(s)
```

I am very new to webscraping and hence this question.

Comment: @Qharr how can I do it?

Comment: Why not just dive into url you have got in `s` in the same way as you did to the main page?

Answer (score 0):

You can find `main_div` tag based on class attribute and use `find_all` method to get a tag by looping over it you can extract href of it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'}
source = requests.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/",headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
main_div=soup.find("div",class_="main-menu2 main-menu-gray")
a_tag=main_div.find_all("a")
for i in a_tag:
    print(i['href'])
```

Output:

```
/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/
/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2019/results/
/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2017/results/
/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2015/results/
/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2013/results/
/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2012/results/
/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2010/results/
/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2008/results/
```

Comment: This code will need for for OP to input every URL to get child URL right?

Comment: I dont get about child URL as per question i extract the url from above result what you want!